# How to save my javascript array to a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

My phonegap/iOS application has a file named **data.js** which contains an array. The application works with this array and some changes are stored into it.

Now when the user quits my application I want it to save the changes to the **data.js** file. Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE** This is my array (the only thing in **data.js**):

```
var data = [
    [0, "A", "B", "0", "0"],
    [1, "C", "D", "0", "0"],
    [2, "E", "F", "0", "0"],
    ...
];
```

**SOLVED!**
I used JSON to stringify my array and save it to the localStorage. It only has to work with Mobile Safari, so this is a good solution. Thanks for giving me the hints that made me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using phonegap than for sure you can work with file system.
Solution is to encode your array into `JSON` using [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method in JQuery.

Once you encode your array you will get `JSON` string which you have to store in a file using PhoneGap's `Filewriter()` function. For more detail on that visit this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter).

I hope it helped you :-).

Comment: Stunning! I will try that out tomorrow and post if I managed to get it working.

Comment: This is the way to go but one word of caution. The data.js file is included as part of your application so it won't be modifiable. On first startup of your app you should copy data.js to the apps filesystem and read/write that file.

Comment: Well, you don't need to modify the data.js , you can store your array in.json file just before app is closed.And when app is started you can ajax that .json file and get the array and use it in your app.

Comment: This all sounds exactly like what I want to do. My problem now is that I can't imagine which code I would be using to do it. How would you code it? I added my array in my first entry.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot tamper with the file system directly. You can do one of two things:

1. Save the changes onto a cookie and read it the next time
2. <s>Send the changes (via AJAX) to a PHP file which would generate a downloadable file on the server, and serve it to the client.</s>

There are probably more solutions, but these are the most reasonable two I can think of.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentionend that I don't want the app to communicate with a server.

Comment: Yes, you probably should have :)

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap (at http://phonegap.com/tools/) is suggesting Lawnchair: http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

so you'd read that file into data.js instead of storing the data literally there

Answer (score 0):

You could also save your array (or better yet its members) using localStorage, a key/value storage that stores your data locally, even when the user quits your app. Check out the [guide in the Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html).

Answer (score 0):

use [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) to save the array as a JSON object. The JSON object will be there in the memory till you clear the data for the application.

 If you want to save it permanently to a file on the local filesystem then i guess you can write a phonegap plugin to sent the data across to the native code of plugin which will create/open a file and save it.