# How to save a javascript array as an external file and then load it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a webpage in which the user types some text into a text field and this text is shown below. I managed to display the text that the user types by adding this text into an array every time they click de submit button. I want this "comments" written by the user to the displayed every time someone loads the webpage, regardless of who typed the comment. So it would be kind of like a guestbook. 
What I tried to do so far is to save the array in an external file and then load this file when the page reloads. The problem is that I haven't find a way to do this when searching in stackoverflow and google.
Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Speak your mind</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><h1>Speak Your Mind</h1></div>
    <div id ="description"><h2>Share with the world whatever is in your mind right now!        </h2></div>
    <div id="writeText"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="writeThought"></textarea></div>
    <div id="submitThoughtContainer"><button id="submitYourThought">Submit Your Thought! </button></div>
    <div id="thoughtsContainer"></div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var thoughts = [];

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var writeThought = document.getElementById('writeThought');
var recentThought;
var thoughtsContainer = document.getElementById('thoughtsContainer');
var submitYourThought = document.getElementById('submitYourThought');
var thoughtsTemporal = "";

submitYourThought.addEventListener('click', function() {
    recentThought = writeThought.value;
    thoughts.splice(0, 0, recentThought);
    writeThought.value = "";
    thoughtsTemporal = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < thoughts.length; i++) {
        thoughtsTemporal += '<div class="thoughts">'+ thoughts[i] +'</div>';
        thoughtsContainer.innerHTML = "" + thoughtsTemporal;
        }
    });                      
});
```

Comment: you shoud have a backend or use localstorage

Comment: To share data between different clients you need a back-end server. e.g appengine https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Comment: Like the others above, you have to use a back end server and then use a server-side language for processing the data (i.e. PHP, Rails, Django, or even Node.js etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save my javascript array to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717439/how-to-save-my-javascript-array-to-a-file)